# How to change NA square color with ggplot's `geom_tile()`

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
heatmap <- tibble(col1 = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3)),
                  col2 = rep(c("I", "II", "III"), 3),
                  col3 = c(1:8, NA))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   col1  col2   col3
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A     I         1
#> 2 A     II        2
#> 3 A     III       3
#> 4 B     I         4
#> 5 B     II        5
#> 6 B     III       6
#> 7 C     I         7
#> 8 C     II        8
#> 9 C     III      NA

ggplot(heatmap, aes(col1, col2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = col3))
```

[image: heat map 4]

The heat map above has a grey square representing the "NA" value in my `heatmap` data frame. How do I change the color of this square to red? This code does not work. It is just red outlines.

```
ggplot(heatmap, aes(col1, col2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = col3), color = "red")
```

[image: heat map 5]

I assume the `NA` square is the lack of a drawing, and is transparent and showing some type of ggplot base background (the grey square you actually see). Maybe I need to change this base background color? Do you know?

Comment: See `na.value` argument in `scale_fill_gradient`

Comment: ```ggplot(heatmap, aes(col1, col2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = col3), color = "red") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(na.value = "green")```